# Is it possible to use the "Hamburger icon" animation from Android in another button?

Tags: android, animation, button, icons

I would like to have two Hamburger icon with its animation in two different positions, one button in the usually place (at the left in my toolbar) and other in a button placed inside the Navigation Drawer.

Looking the Android documentation I couldn't see anything talking about using the hamburguer icon in other position more than the toolbar, so I would like to know if there is an easy way to implement or copy the animation to other position/button without having to do my own animation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is hamburger icon?

Comment: The "hamburger icon" is the icon with three stripes and an arrow usually placed in an app toolbar which becomes animated when you open and close a navigation drawer.

Answer (score 9):

So I am a little late on this one (only just came across the same problem). You can use the underlying drawable [`DrawerArrowDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/drawable/DrawerArrowDrawable.html) from the v7 support library. It handles the drawing based on it's progress `setProgress(floatValue)` but you need to handle the animation between states. I did this by wrapping it with a [`ValueAnimator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html). See example below:

```
final DrawerArrowDrawable drawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(this);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
  @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    drawable.setProgress((Float)animation.getAnimatedValue());
  }
});

...

// burger to arrow
animator.start();

...

// arrow to burger
animator.reverse();
```

This is an untested adaption from a production app, should work though :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several implementations of the hamburger menu icon animation. You could try to use one of those. Take a look at this project:

https://github.com/keklikhasan/LDrawer

You could use the animation without the drawer. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Natan, I think this is what I need, I'm going to try it and then I'll tell you.

Comment: I have been seeing that library but I can't see how I could implement it in my own button or in other place than the toolbar